# Ranking Customers SQL Server Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need a little help:

---

ON EDIT: I am trying to determine who are my top 40% customers based on sales. Then, removing those customers, give me the top 30%. Then removing those two datasets, who are now mytop 20%, etc

---

Here is the scenario:.  Let's say we have a total of $1,000,000 in sales.  I want to have a customer ranking system to rank A, B, C and D customers to see who my best customers are.

"A" customers transact 40% of total revenues --- $400k
"B" customers transact the next 30%              --- $300k
"C" customers transact the next 20%              --- $200k
"D" customers transact the final 10% of total revenues  --- $100k

Here is my SQL:

```
declare @TotalTotal decimal(18,2)
declare @ATotalRankTotal decimal(18,2)
declare @BTotalRankTotal decimal(18,2)
declare @CTotalRankTotal decimal(18,2)
declare @DTotalRankTotal decimal(18,2)

SET @TotalTotal = 1000000

set @ATotalRankTotal = @TotalTotal * .40
set @BTotalRankTotal = @ATotalRankTotal + (@TotalTotal * .30)
set @CTotalRankTotal = @BTotalRankTotal + (@TotalTotal * .20)
set @DTotalRankTotal = @CTotalRankTotal + (@TotalTotal * .10)

select
        CustomerName
        , sum(TotalSales)
        , TotalCustomerRank = CASE
            WHEN SUM(sum(TotalSales)) over (order by SUM(TotalSales) desc) <= @ATotalRankTotal then
                'A'
            WHEN SUM(sum(TotalSales)) over (order by SUM(TotalSales) desc) > @ATotalRankTotal and SUM(sum(TotalSales)) over (order by SUM(TotalSales) desc) <= @BTotalRankTotal then
                'B'
            WHEN SUM(sum(TotalSales)) over (order by SUM(TotalSales) desc) > @BTotalRankTotal and SUM(sum(TotalSales)) over (order by SUM(TotalSales) desc) <= @CTotalRankTotal then
                'C'
            else
                'D'
            end
    from 
        Customers
    GROUP BY 
        CustomerName
```

The problem I have come up with is that I might not have a customer that had $400k or more in sales, so I would never know who my "A" customers are.

Any ideas on how to write the script to determine which customers take up my top 40% of revenue (my "A" customers), which customers take up the NEXT 30% (my "B" customers), which customers take up the NEXT 20% (my "C" customers), and which customers take up the final 10% (my "D" Customers)?

Comment: I'm not sure one sample data set is enough, might need to supply multiple scenarios.   I don't think you have a good handle on exactly what you want.   "which customers take up my top 40% of revenue" isn't exactly a clear description.

Comment: Just add another column, and filter each case  Where SalesDept = "A" for 1st case, or = "B" for 2nd case, ...

Comment: I have a great handle of what I am trying to do, probably just didn't explain it right.  Who are my top 40% of my customers based on sales.  Then, removing those customers, now who are my top 30%. Then removing those two datasets, who are now by top 20%, etc.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, sample data with the associated desired result for each of your scenarios would be *very* helpful.

Comment: Have you thought about using RANK() ?

Comment: I smell recursive cte. But yes, sample data would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs very fast on Northwind.  Should be just what you want.  It focuses on top 40% of SALES, not top 40% of the number of customers.

Yields the following results
[image]

```
DECLARE 
    @TotalTotal INT = 0;

DECLARE @st TABLE
(
    CustomerID  nchar(5),
    CustTotal   INT,
    RunningTotal INT,
    RunningPCT   INT,
    CustRank    nchar(1)
);

DECLARE
    @CustomerID  nchar(5),
    @CustTotal   INT,
    @RunningTotal INT = 0,
    @RunningPCT   INT = 0,  
    @CustRank    nchar(1)= ' ';

DECLARE c CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR

        SELECT
              oo.CustomerID

              ,SUM( od.[UnitPrice] * od.[Quantity] ) as CustTotal

          FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details] as od
          left join [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders] as oo
          on od.OrderID = oo.OrderID
          left join [Northwind].[dbo].[Products] as pd
          on od.ProductID = pd.ProductID

          Group by oo.CustomerID
          order by SUM( od.[UnitPrice] * od.[Quantity] ) desc
    ;

-- get the Denominator for the Percent ranking  
OPEN c; 
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CustomerID, @CustTotal;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @TotalTotal = @TotalTotal + @CustTotal;
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CustomerID, @CustTotal;
END
CLOSE c;

-- compute Rank for each customer
OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CustomerID, @CustTotal;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @CustTotal;
    SET @RunningPCT   =  (@RunningTotal * 100 / @TotalTotal);
    SET @CustRank = Case
        When @RunningPCT <= 40 Then 'A'
        When @RunningPCT <= 70 Then 'B'
        When @RunningPCT <= 90 Then 'C'
        Else 'D' End ;
    INSERT @st(CustomerID, CustTotal,  RunningTotal, RunningPCT, CustRank)
        SELECT @CustomerID,  @CustTotal, @RunningTotal, @RunningPCT, @CustRank;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CustomerID, @CustTotal;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c; 

-- Show the results 
Select @TotalTotal;
Select * From @st;
```

Comment: While I was trying to avoid using cursors, this did do the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going by this sentence:

> Who are my top 40% of my customers based on sales.

In other words, if you have 10 customers, you want the top 4, regardless of what percentage of total revenue they account for.   If that's not what you meant to ask, then your question still isn't clear enough.

You can get this with the built-in [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. Using `NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY Revenue)` to put your customers in buckets of 10% of your total number of customers, you can get the A,B,C,D by checking this value in ranges.

Suppose you use the above NTILE function to generate a column called `MyNtile` then you could do something like:

```
CASE WHEN MyNtile <= 4 THEN 'A'
     WHEN MyNtile BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 'B'
     etc..
```